# Example in Combination, is there any solution?!

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Is there any idea to solve such a question?

I have $40$ pens that includes $20$ white pens and $20$ black pens, I decide to distribute these pens among $4$ students that every student gets at least $2$ pens and at most $7$ pens from each color (thus, each student must receive at least $2$ black pens and $2$ white pens). if the number of possible ways to do this distribution be $n$,  the sum of two rightmost digits of $n$ is equal to $13$. How this value calculated?

Note: the order is not important. Thus, switching the pens between two students does not give a different allocation.

Comment: What is "the sum of two rightmost bit of $n$"? Can you compute it for $n = 65537$? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: we must first computer n, and then calculate sum of two rightmost bit @Abstraction

Comment: Does the condition "every student gets at least $2$ pens and at most $7$ pens from each color" require that each student get at least $2$ of each color?   (it isn't clear, grammatically, whether the clause "from each color" refers to both conditions or just the last).

Comment: When I read "bits", I think about digits of the binary record of a number. But then sum of two bits can't exceed $2$. That's why I ask to provide such sum for $65537_{10} = 10000000000000001_2$

Comment: @lulu from each color at least 2 and at most 7 must be delivered to each student.

Comment: @Abstraction No, I correct it

Comment: Thanks.  I suggest editing the question...it isn't clear as written.

Comment: is it possible help me with editing ? @lulu

Comment: Take a look at the change I made and tell me if it is ok.  Also:  does the order matter?  That is, is I give $7B$ and $7W$ to Amy, but only $6$ each to Bob, do I get a different distribution if I switch those two?

Comment: @lulu it's okey now.

Comment: I think it's not important @lulu

Comment: So the order doesn't matter? If you confirm that, I'll edit again to include it.

Comment: yes the order is not important , thanks @lulu

Comment: Note:  the solution I posted below has an error in the unordered case.  I don't have time to address it now, but I'll get to it later.  In the meanwhile, I'll leave it up because I expect the raw calculations it contains are still helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach based upon *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*.

We encode white pens with $x$ and black pens with $y$. The term
\begin{align*}\
x^3y^6
\end{align*}
means three white pens and six black pens.

> The different possibilities to distribute *at least* $2$ pens and *at most* $7$ pens from each color to a student can be represented as
>   \begin{align*}
> (x^2+x^3&+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5+y^6+y^7)\\
> &=x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)y^2(1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5)\\
> &=x^2\frac{1-x^6}{1-x} y^2 \frac{1-y^6}{1-y}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*

> It is convenient for later use to also mark the pens independent of their color. In order to so we introduce a variable $t$ and get according to (1) a generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x,y;t)&=(xt)^2\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt} (yt)^2 \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\\
> &=x^2y^2t^4\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt}\cdot  \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since we are interested in the number of different distributions of $40$ pens to four students, we have to look for the coefficient $[t^{40}]$ in $\left(A(x,y;t)\right)^4$.
>
> We are also limited in  the maximum number of  white  and black pens by $20$. So, we have to select coefficients of powers of $x^k$ and $y^l$ up to $k=l=20$.
>
> Each student has at least two pens of each color and four students have a total of at least $8$ pens from one color.
>
> So, we  have as range $8\leq k,l \leq 20$ for the powers of $x^k$ and $y^l$.
>
> We obtain from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=8}^{20}&\sum_{l=8}^{20}[x^ky^lt^{40}]\left(A(x,y;t)\right)^4\\
> &\sum_{k=8}^{20}\sum_{l=8}^{20}[x^ky^lt^{40}]x^8y^8t^{16}\left(\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt}\cdot  \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\right)^4\\
> &\sum_{k=8}^{20}\sum_{l=8}^{20}[x^{k-8}y^{l-8}t^{24}]\left(\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt}\cdot  \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\right)^4\\
> &\sum_{k=0}^{12}\sum_{l=0}^{12}[x^{k}y^{l}t^{24}]\left(\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt}\cdot  \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\right)^4\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

With the help from Wolfram Alpha we find as coefficient of $t^{24}$

\begin{align*}
[t^{24}]&\left(\frac{1-(xt)^6}{1-xt}\cdot  \frac{1-(yt)^6}{1-y}\right)^4\\
&=x^4y^4\left(35x^{16}+224x^{15}y+800x^{14}y^2+2080x^{13}y^3+4375x^{12}y^4\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad+7840x^{11}y^5+11680x^{10}y^6+14560x^9y^7\\
&\qquad\qquad+\color{blue}{15625}x^8y^8\\
&\qquad\qquad+14560x^7y^9+11680x^6y^{10}+7840x^5y^{11}+4375x^4y^{12}\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+2080x^3y^{13}+800x^2y^{14}+224xy^{15}+35y^{16}\right)
\end{align*}

> According   to (3) we have to sum up the  coefficients    of all terms $x^ky^l$  with   $0\leq k,l\leq 12$. We observe the blue one 
>   $$\color{blue}{15625}x^8y^8$$
>     is the only one  which fulfils the constraint and so the solution is $15625$.

Comment: I got the same result using a simple Python script ($125$ ways for distributing the white pens and $125$ ways for distributing the black pens, thus $125^2=15625$ ways for distributing the pens). What I don't get is, that according to the question, the sum of the $2$ rightmost digits should be equal to $13$, and here this sum is equal to $2+5=7$. So where's the catch?

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't think the sum of the $2$ rightmost give $13$. Btw in my first approach I overlooked the restriction of at most $20$ pens of a specific color and calculated just $[t^{24}]$ which means summing up all the coefficients of $x^ky^l$ in my expression above resulting in  $98813$, with $13$ at the end but also not a sum ....

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out to be unexpectedly tricky.

We look first at the white pens. We first give 2 to each student. Then the remaining 12 can be distributed between them so that no student gets more than 5 of the 12. The possibilities are:

(A) 5430, 5421, 24 possibilities each; (B) 5520, 5331, 4431, 5322, 4332, 12 possibilities each; (C) 5511, 4422, 6 possibilities each; (D) 4440, 4 possibilities and (E) 3333, 1 possibility. Total: 125.

The analysis for the black pens is the same. So the total number would be $125^2=15625$, except that there is one more condition: "switching the pens between students does not give a different allocation". In other words the students are regarded as indistinguishable. So there are only 11 possibilities for the first colour.

But it is now tricky working out the possibility for the second colour. If the first is type (E) 3333, then the students are still indistinguishable, so there are $11$ possibilities for the second colour.

If the first is type (D) 4440, then one student is distinguished, so there are 4 possibilities for type (A) such as 5430, three for type (B) such as 5520, two for type (C) such as 5511, two for type (D) 4440 and one for type (E) 3333. Hence total $2\cdot4+5\cdot3+2\cdot2+1\cdot2+1\cdot1=30$.

If the first is type (C) such as 5511, then there are 6 poss for type (A) such as 5430, 4 for type (B) such as 5520, 3 for type (C) such as 5511, 2 for type (D) 4440, and 1 for type (E) 3333. Hence total $2\cdot6+5\cdot4+2\cdot3+1\cdot2+1\cdot1=41$.

If the first is type (B) such as 5520, then there are 12 poss for type (A) such as 5430, 7 for type (B) such as 5520, 4 for type (C) such as 5511, 3 for type (D) 4440, and 1 for type (E) 3333. Hence total $2\cdot12+5\cdot7+2\cdot4+1\cdot3+1\cdot1=71$.

If the first is type (A) 5430, then there are 24 poss for type (A) such as 5430, 12 for type (B) such as 5520, 6 for type (C) such as 5511, 4 for type (D) 4440, and 1 for type (E) 3333. Hence total $2\cdot24+5\cdot12+2\cdot6+1\cdot4+1\cdot1=125$.

So the final tally is $2\cdot125+5\cdot71+2\cdot41+1\cdot30+1\cdot11=728$. Note that the sum of the last two digits is 10, which does not agree with that claimed by the OP.

Comment: Note:  having assigned the whites in some arbitrary way, you now need to assign the blacks in an ordered way.  So you get $11\times 125$ variants in that case, not $11^2$.  Still doesn't get you to $13$ though.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I made that same mistake, of course.  I'll delete my comment in a minute...and this one too.

Comment: @lulu No need, it is quite a helpful comment to any reader.

Comment: @lulu Grateful for any checking or independent calculation! It is easy to make mistakes in this kind of thing.

Comment: It looks correct to me, but then I've made so many errors in this problem that I have ceased to trust myself. At least:   I redid it from scratch, more or less following the same approach, and got the same answer.